# Spacing and padding / margin in bootstrap row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, margin, padding

[image: This is how I want the container to appear]

I am having difficulties with understanding padding, margin and gutter.

Can anyone help me with getting the styling right for this design? I am not getting any space between and around the columns.

My current coding is:

```
<div class = "container">
    <div class = "row">
        <div class = "col-md-12">
            <h3>Heading</h3>
        </div>
        <div class = "col-md-12">
            <div class = "row">
                <div class = "col-md-8" style = "border: solid 1px #003c70;">
                    Some text
                </div>
                <div class = "col-md-4" style = "border: solid 1px #003c70;">
                    Some text
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the problem you're having?

Comment: Updated question with tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add an extra `div` for `border` and `padding` styling like below.

```
<div class = "col-md-8">
    <div class="some-class">
        Some text
    </div>
</div>
```

check this [codepen](http://codepen.io/Venugopal46/pen/NxNgEX)

Answer (score 0):

add a div inside of your colm

```css
body{
  background: #ddd;
}
header{
  background: blue;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  color:#fff;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.boder{
  border: 1px solid #333;
  min-height: 350px;
  padding:10px;
}
.wrapper{
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<header>
  <h4>THIS  IS HEADER</h4>
</header>
<div class = "container">
    <div class = "row wrapper">
        <div class = "col-md-12">
            <div class = "row">
                <div class = "col-md-8">
                  <div class="boder">
                    blah blah..
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class = "col-md-4">
                    <div class="boder">
                    blah blah..
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```